# Variables inserted into email message from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

So I am sending an email in codeigniter where the message is coming from the database.

What I am wanting to do, is put the posted variables into the html formatted email in the database.

For sending the email I have the following in my controller:

```
    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->load->model('cms');

    $message = $this->cms->Order_Email();

    $this->email->from('info@candykingdom.org', 'Candy Kingdom');
    $this->email->to($this->input->post('billingEmail'));

    $this->email->subject('Order Confirmation');
    $this->email->message($message->content);   

    $this->email->send();
```

Now a portion of my email that comes from the database is:

```
<td>
   <p>Hi</p>
   <p>Sometimes all you want is to send a simple HTML email with a basic design.</p>
   <h1>Really simple HTML email template</h1>
...
```

I am trying to make the `<p>Hi</p>` line turn into: `<p>Hi John,</p>` I have tried changing that line to the following:

```
<p>Hi <?php echo $this->input->post('billingFname'); ?>,</p>
```

as well as:

```
 <p>Hi '.$this->input->post('billingFName").',</p>
```

But in the completed and sent email it displays just like the above in the email. Without replacing the php with the actual variable.

So what I am asking is, what do I type in the stored email message to make the php code replace the php with the actual variable?

For examples, let's use `John` as `$this->input->post('billingFName');`

**Just a thought**

Maybe this would be better achieved with a templating library? like this: 
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach I've seen is using vars you substitute via str_replace:

The html of your email has some vars you know to substitute, as `#USERNAME#`. In your db you store

```
<td>
   <p>Hi #USERNAME#</p>
   <p>Sometimes all you want is to send a simple HTML email with a basic design.</p>
   <h1>Really simple HTML email template</h1>
```

Then, you change #USERNAME# via a str_replace when you get it from the DB:

```
$message->content = str_replace( '#USERNAME#', $var_with_username, $message->content );
```

You may even use arrays in your str_replace, to subsitute as many vars as you want, check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-examples for more info.

Comment: I will approve as soon as I can, but could you provide an example of the array? Even with just two var's?

Comment: check the link with the example, it's from php.net, XD